# How to get 2x favicon in Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

It seems `chrome://favicon/` only allows me to get a 16x16 favicon, and it looks blurry in Retina screens. What if I want to get a 2x retina ready favicon?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These urls should work:

- 16px for retina: `chrome://favicon/size/16@2x/http://www.apple.com/`
- 48px: `chrome://favicon/size/48/http://www.apple.com/`

Notes:

- Some versions of Chrome may always return a 16x16 icon (or a subpar stretched version).
- Many (most?) sites provide only a 16x16 icon and there's nothing you can do about it.
- The favicon cache gets an icon only when the corresponding web page is completely loaded.

Comment: Niiiice. Thanks! From what I can tell, the 16@2x URL will return a retina-friendly favicon where one is available, otherwise return the standard/16px one. Is that correct?

Comment: 16@2x for retina saves my day!