# Display icon of Bookmark

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, bookmarks

So i am working on a Chrome Extension that manages the user's bookmarks. What i want to do is display a box (a div) displaying the image associated with each bookmark and it's name under it. I am able to get the title and url stuff to work. But am unable to retrieve the icon associated with each bookmark.

Can someon please tell me how to do this ?

For reference my JS file is :

```
function list_bookmarks(bookmarks){
var i;
for ( i=0; i<bookmarks.length ; i++) {

  console.log("Works" + i);
  var current_bookmark = bookmarks[i];
  if(current_bookmark.url) { 

  var icon = document.createElement('div');
  icon.id = "pict";
  icon.style.backgroundImage = current_bookmark.FAVICON; // Something here *
  document.body.appendChild(icon);

  var item = document.createElement('a');
  item.className = 'block';
  var linkText = document.createTextNode(current_bookmark.title);
  item.appendChild(linkText);
  item.title = current_bookmark.title;
  item.href = current_bookmark.url;
  document.body.appendChild(item);


   console.log(current_bookmark.title);    }
 if(current_bookmark.children){  list_bookmarks(current_bookmark.children);}                

}

 }


window.onload = function(){ 
console.log("Listing Bookmarks Now :");
chrome.bookmarks.getTree(function(list){

   list_bookmarks(list);    

 });
  };
```

Thank You So Much.:)

Comment: See [How to get 2x favicon in Chrome extension](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33348120)

Comment: And it needs a special permission, `"chrome://favicon/*"`

Comment: what do i write in the js file :  icon.style.backgroundImage = ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Add `chrome://favicon/` to the `permissions` field in `manifest.json`
2. `icon.style.backgroundImage = 'url(chrome://favicon/' + current_bookmark.url + ')';`

See [Issue 45474](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=45474) for more details.